# how to make the prices add over and over again in c++?

Tags: c++

I am just a beginner in C++. I am still having a problem of adding the prices if I confirmed purchase. I want to hold the prices if I decided to confirmed the purchase. If I want to buy more items, and buy the same thing again for example, if my choice is 1, and purchase 1, and confirm the purchase, and want to buy more items, and decided to bought the same thing again which is 1, i want to add the first purchase to my last purchase. There is no limit if I want to buy the same thing over and over unless I do not want to view more items.

```
  #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    //My Function
    double Peripheral (int quantity, double price) {
        double result;
        result = quantity * price;
        return result;
    }

    int main()
    {
        int choice;
        int purchase;
        int quantity;
        double totalPeripheral1 = 0;
        double totalPeripheral2 = 0;
        double totalPeripheral3 = 0;
        double totalPeripheral4 = 0;
        char view;
        char confirm;
        char buyMore;
        char look;
        double alloy, apex, kraken, aorus;
        double oppo, alpha, rog, huawei;
        double ps4, nintendo, xbox, wii;
        alloy = 69.99;
        apex = 199;
        kraken = 90;
        aorus = 60;

    do {
        cout << "What type of items would you like to view?" << endl;
        cout << " [1] Peripherals" << endl;
        cout << " [2] Mobile Phones" << endl;
        cout << " [3] Consoles" << endl;
        cout << " [4] Exit" << endl;
        cout << "Enter your choice: ";
        cin >> choice;


        if (choice == 1) {
            cout << "--------------------" << endl;
            cout << "What peripherals would you like to purchase?" << endl;
            cout << "[1] HyperX Alloy FPS PRO - $69.99" << endl;
            cout << "[2] SteelSeries APEX PRO - $199" << endl;
            cout << "[3] Razer Kraken X - $90" << endl;
            cout << "[4] AORUS K7 - $60" << endl;
            cout << "[5] BACK TO MENU"  << endl;
            cout << "Enter your choice: ";
            cin >> purchase;
            cout << "--------------------" << endl;


          if (purchase == 1) {

            cout << "How many would you like to purchase? ";
            cin >> quantityPeripheral1;
            totalPeripheral1 += Peripheral(quantityPeripheral1, alloy);
            cout << "The total price for that is " << totalPeripheral1 << endl;
            cout << "Confirm the Purchase? [Y]/[N]: ";
            cin >> confirm;

            if (confirm == 'Y') {
                cout << "Would you like to buy more items? [Y]/[N]: ";
                cin >> buyMore;
            }

            else if (confirm == 'N') {
                cout << "Do you still want to look for items? [Y]/[N]: ";
                cin >> look;

                if (look == 'N') {
                    break;
                }
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }
         cout << totalPeripheral1 << endl;
}
}

     }

    }

        while (purchase == 5 || buyMore == 'Y' || look == 'Y');
          cout << "--------------------" << endl;
```

Comment: You're asking a lot of questions about this program in quick succession. Please spend some time on your problems before resorting to asking! A few hours is not enough work, to be honest.

Comment: It's usually considered a bad idea to use floating point (`double`/`float`) to represent currency (e.g. dollars and cents) since floating point variables cannot store all multiples of `0.1` or `0.01` exactly (for exactly the same reason that one third cannot be presented exactly in a finite number of decimal places, except that floating point works with base 2 not base 10) and errors build up. Instead, use a structure with two integral members for major and minor currency units (dollars and cents). It isn't difficult to implement addition/subtraction/multiplication/etc for such a structure.

Comment: @Peter It is when you are a total beginner, who has trouble keeping a running total, and probably hasn't used a structure yet.

Comment: @john - That can be simplified to tracking a total number of cents (or whatever minor currency unit).   Keeping a running total isn't too difficult with integers.  Printing `Total/100` and `Total%100` with a `'.'` in between (to, say, get dollars and cents respectively) isn't too difficult.    The essential skill in coding is picking the right tools for the job, not picking a tool and using it for a job it doesn't work for.   And floating point is the wrong tool for working with currency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add, then you have to add

```
totalPeripheral1 = Peripheral(quantityPeripheral1, alloy);
```

should be

```
totalPeripheral1 += Peripheral(quantityPeripheral1, alloy);
```

`=` copies the value on the right hand side to the variable on the left hand side, this is called assignment. But `+=` adds the value on the right hand side to the variable on the left hand side.

And obviously you don't need four total peripheral variables, only one.

Comment: Is it the same if I only make it only one totalPeripheral if I choose 2,3,4 and have the same condition in the purchase part? because, in peripherals, so the logic that I thought is that totalPeripheral1 + totalPeripheral2 + totalPeripheral3 + totalPeripheral4

Comment: @grantfasx Do you need separate totals for each of the different type of peripherals? If yes, then you'll need four variables. But I was thinking you only needed one overall total, so I suggested only one variable.

Comment: Yes. Because I have 4 choices for the peripherals, if it is 1 2 3 or 4, I just did not include the code of them since I need first to accomplish the first condition. And, btw. I tried +=, when I try to buy more items, and confirm the purchase, the price of the first one is not adding to the 2nd one, or in the 3rd one.

Comment: @grantfasx I'm probably a little confused with what you are trying to do. Just because you have four choices does not mean you have to have four variables. It depends on what you are trying to calculate, as I said, if you want to calculate the overall total of everything, you only need one variable. But if you want to show separate totals for each peripheral then you need four variables. But I'm still unsure about what you want so I'll leave it to you.